# How to start an activity at a given time in future?

Tags: android-intent, android-activity, android-pendingintent

I want to start an activity on a particular time if the app is open. Basically I am having a Firestore Timestamp (future timestamp only), I want to start the activity in the timestamp time only. Also the user should not be able to hack the time (like increase their local device time)and start the activity before only. **The activity should only start automatically if the user is inside the app....If app is closed or app is in background the activity should not start**. I heard somewhere to use pending intent but how can I implement this i am not getting the direction.

Comment: It is their browser. The user will always be able to kick off some event if the logic is not server side. You can use a browser timestamp and then once reached ask an API to kick off the work if the time is valid and if the api verifies the timestamp from Firestone.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a `JobScheduler` and on its `onStartJob` you can start your activity.

```
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        val jobScheduler =
            context.getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE) as JobScheduler?
        val componentName = ComponentName(context, MyJobService::class.java)
        val jobInfoObj =
            JobInfo.Builder(REQUEST_CODE, componentName)
                .setMinimumLatency(x)
                .build()
        jobScheduler?.schedule(jobInfoObj)
    }
```

In the above code in `setMinimumLatency(x)` you can replace x with the amount of time that you need.
also `MyJobService` is a class which you have to implement it like this:

```
class MyJobService : JobService() {

override fun onStartJob(params: JobParameters?): Boolean {
    return false
}

override fun onStopJob(params: JobParameters?): Boolean {
    return false
}
```

}

then in `onStartJob` you can simply start your activity.

just make sure that you add your service to the manifest.

Comment: Thanks for you comment to this..but if possible can you show some code or github regarding this? It will boom my work

Comment: yeah sure, I edited my answer. But If you search JobScheduler you can find many many useful resources.